# Verified user in Django

Tags: django

I want to allow only verified users by site admin should be able to post blog on site

so how can i check the is_verifieduser field defined in model while rendering template

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):

 user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT)

 phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12,default="") 

 is_verifieduser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

     def __str__(self):
       return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% if user.userprofileinfo.is_verifieduser %}
```

Comment: thanks it worked, I am new to django is it a good approach to use this condition in html template rather than in views